# delete an image file which i Saved

Tags: powershell

i have script where i extract the icon so i can use it later in my script to import it into SCCM.

during the script i have to save the file as bmp. for that i use following code.

```
$Iitem = Get-ChildItem -Path "$PSScriptRoot" -Include "Icon.*" -File -Recurse
$objVar.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$Iitem");

$objVar.Icon.ToBitmap().Save("$path\Icon.bmp")
```

after that i take the bmp and save it as .jpg

```
$image = [drawing.image]::FromFile("$path\Icon.bmp")
```

now i want to Delete the .bmp File but i cant because the process is still in use... i can only delete it after i close PS

i tryed to do the bmp save part as a job

```
Invoke-Command $objApplication.Icon.ToBitmap().Save("$path\Icon fuer Anwendungskatalog.bmp") -AsJob
```

which creates the .bmp file even though i get an Error because of missing Session param...
AND the file can't be deleted.

so the Question is how can i crate the file and delete it during runtime
OR how can i save the icon directly as a jpg.

thanks in advance

best regards

Comment: Investigate if this `$image = [drawing.image]::FromFile("$path\Icon.bmp")` opens the file but does not close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$image` is [System.Drawing.Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.8) which implements [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8). And you should *always* dispose IDisposable.

In this case it will keep the lock on the file until you call Dispose().

In PowerShell, there is no `using` statement, but you can use try + finally:

```
try {
  $image = ...
}
finally {
  if ($image) { $image.Dispose() }
}
```

Comment: thanks Lasse and Marsze... never thought about it, that it could be open.. eventhough it says so... Man what would i do without this site and people like you :D